# React: Nested Reusable Composition Components within a Higher Order Component

Tags: reactjs, components, composite-component, higher-order-functions

I've been trying to wrap my head around this problem for a while. I've hacked together a solution that works, until I get any nested divs, then things fall apart. Basically what I'm trying to do is create composition components that live within a higher order component and all share the same current state. I then need to export that so that any file can use those components. So here's what the JSX might look like:

```
<Panel countersStartAt=5>
  <Counter incrementsBy=1 />
  <div>
    <Counter incrementsBy=2 />
  </div>
  <TotalCounter className="someclass" />
</Panel>
```

So the way I want something like this to work is that I have this wrapper Panel component that sets some initial state, say this.state.start = 5. Within Panel, a Counter component would have an onClick handler that increments state.start by incrementsBy. And TotalCounter would be a component that displayed state.start. Of course this is a contrived example, so it would be helpful not to bring up how I could make this particular component better. I'm looking to apply this to a more realistic situation.

The second thing would be how to export those components in a way that I can create the exact code above in a separate file within a stateless component. Hopefully that makes sense.

This is a snippet of what I'm doing to achieve this.

```
  renderChildren = (children) => {
    return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
      if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
        return React.createElement(
          (child.type.name ? this[child.type.name] : child.type),
          child.props
        );
      }
      return child;
    });
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
        {this.renderChildren(this.props.children)}
    )
  };
```

Then outside of the Panel class I'm exporting like so:

`export const Counter = () => null;`

Just so it exposes Counter. The default render of null doesn't happen because I replace Counter with the this.Counter() method within Panel.

**Questions asked in Comments and Other things to consider**

- I am not using Flux or Redux
- Assume that the Panel code snippet is used in several render methods across several projects that do not implement Flux patterns or Redux
- Assume that those code snippets can't be re-written
- How can can Panel, Counter, and TotalCounter be exported? Is it possible to do this for Counter and TotalCounter as they are methods within the Panel class? My research led to no, and creating "dummy" components to be exported so that the current file can use them without errors.

Comment: are you using a flux store?

Comment: are you asking how to implement what you want? aka the panel?

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes, sorry for not being clear. I've implemented it but using a class Panel and the other components inside. Then when I use Panel I just map through all the children and set up state, etc, but this is definitely not the right solution.

Comment: ok, are you using any data storage framework like redux or flux?

Comment: @ryudice I'm not using a flux store.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I'm using meteor for this particular project. I was trying to avoid using a store of any kind. Redux is a little redundant with meteor. I was hoping to solve this by using Panel as a Higher Order Component and figuring the rest out.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I've edited the initial question to show a little more of what I'm doing, but I didn't want it to distract from the "React" way to do this.

Comment: Thats fine :) so why are you exporting a counter Stateless Function here? shouldn't you just export your Counter component and import it here to be used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114179/discussion-between-nate-and-john-ruddell).

Answer (score 1):

To put in an answer here for what we talked about in the chat room

the best way to handle what you want to do without a data management framework like Redux or Flux is to pass your data as props through, like so.

```
class Panel extends Component {

    constructor(){
      super()
      this.state = {count: 5}
    }
    incrementCount = (incrementer) => {
      this.setState({count: this.state.count + incrementer});
    }
    render (){
      return (
        <div>
          <Counter incrementCount={this.incrementCount} count={this.state.count} incrementsBy=2 />
        </div>
      );
    }

}
```

then in your counter..

```
<someElement onClick={ (e) => {this.props.incrementCount(this.props.incrementsBy)} }>{this.props.count}</someElement>
```